# Android MaterialDatePickerDialog theme

Tags: android, datepicker, material-components-android

I'm trying to use date picker dialog from new Google Material lib. Now I stuck with dialogs theming, because I'm working on project with some legacy. Also theme of single activity is not suitable for my purposes (for example there is white primary color and secondary and primary variant etc.)

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_color_background</item>
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/main_color_background</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/main_color_background</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/main_color_background</item>
```

So, MaterialDatePickerDialogBuilder has function `setTheme(resId)`. But when I set my new suitable theme dialog gone very ugly.[Screenshot of ugly dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk9WU.png). I was trying to set any parameters in my theme and it doesn't look better.

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/surface</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/error</item>
</style>
```

May be I forget something? I don't know, what else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case problem solution is to override material themes for date picker dialogs, and set the app theme attributes `materialCalendarTheme`, `materialCalendarFullscreenTheme`.

For example it looks like:

```
<style name="Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendarStyle</item>

    <!-- Header Styles -->
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderLayout">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderDivider">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderDivider
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderTitle
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderSelection">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderConfirmButton">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderConfirmButton
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton">
        @style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton
    </item>

    <!-- Grid Styles -->
    <item name="materialCalendarDay">@style/Widget.Custom.MaterialCalendar.DayTextView
    </item>

    <!-- Action Styles -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">
        @style/Widget.Custom.Button.TextButton.MaterialCalendar.ButtonBar
    </item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">
        @style/Widget.Custom.Button.TextButton.MaterialCalendar.ButtonBar
    </item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">
        @style/Widget.Custom.Button.TextButton.MaterialCalendar.TextButton
    </item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why isn't there any documentation for this? Also where can I find the one of MaterialTimePicker?